# Change Address info in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html, multidimensional-array

Sorry new to Java... I have a need to regularly change details in 3 pages of a website relating to our standby contact person. I am trying to find a way to greatly reduce the changes needed each time the roster changes. I am currently changing the html in each page.

The site is HTML5 with a some css and it has been suggested that best way to do what I need is to create a javascript array in a separate file and use the variables from the array in my HTML.
I have a list of names and my array has the details I need to display ie name1 name2, phone1, phone2, and email.

The best way I can think of to satisfy the simplicity aspect is to create a 2 dimension array of contact details and a separate variable(onCall) that identifies which line of the array should populate the html pages. I am hoping that I would then only need to change the onCall variable to change the details displayed.

Do I have the best approach?... Is it possible/practical to do this in CSS?

I have not yet worked out how to call the variables from the separate file.

Comment: when you say _new to Java_ you mean _new to JavaScript_? do you try something? can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

First you create new JavaScript file with array, or objects can be more suitable for you:

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", phone:555777555, mobile:6664444333, email:"John.Doe@gmail.com"};
```

Please look for some JavaScript tutorials, for example [JavaScript Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Next you include you .js file in every HTML:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

After that you can put object data in HTML (check the same tutorial above):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking through some of the Javascript tutorials and thought the switch option would give me the least work going forward. Are there any issues with the following approach?  thx Muzza

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var Contact = 3;   // Change this number to select the incomming Contact person
  switch (Contact) {
    case 0:
    Contact = "Brown"; F_Name = "Fredda"; Email = "fredda@email.com"; M_Phone = "0400 400 400";
    break;
case 1:
    Contact = "Clyde"; F_Name = "Fredda"; Email = "fredda@email.com"; M_Phone = "0400 400 400";
    break;
case 2:
    Contact = "Dennis"; F_Name = "Fredda"; Email = "fredda@email.com"; M_Phone = "0400 400 400";
    break;
case 3:
    Contact = "Elthorp"; F_Name = "Fredda"; Email = "fredda@email.com"; M_Phone = "0400 400 400";
    break;
case 4:
    Contact = "Furgusson"; F_Name = "Fredda"; Email = "fredda@email.com"; M_Phone = "0400 400 400";
    break;

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "For enquiries please call or email " + F_Name+" on "+M_Phone;


document.write (F_Name+" "+Contact+" is our person on call this week. ");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```